# Replacing string in a file with a new string

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, replace

I have a list of strings in a text file. The strings are morning, night, sun, moon. What I am trying to do is to replace one of these strings with another string. For example, I would input morning to remove and replace it with afternoon. I am getting an error saying "builtins.ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list" when the string clearly is in the list.

```
def main():
    x = input("Enter a file name: ")
    file = open(x , "r+")
    y = input("Enter the string you want to replace: ")
    z = input("Enter the string you to replace it with: ")
    list = file.readlines()
    list.remove(y)
    list.append(z)
    file.write(list)
    print(file.read())

main()
```

If there is a better way of achieving the same results doing it another way, let me know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You mean editing the file in place without creating another one ?

Comment: First, please do not ever call your variables `list` because `list()` is a built-in function. Second, your strings in `list` have line breaks `'\n'` at the end. You should strip them off before attempting the `remove`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

- The [*str.replace()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) function is the simplest way to replace strings, `s.replace(y, z)`.
- The [*re.sub()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function will let you search for patterns and replace with strings: `re.sub(y, z, s)`.
- The [*fileinput*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) module will allow you to modify in-place.

Here's one way to do it:

```
import fileinput
import re

with fileinput.input(files=('file1.txt', 'file2.txt'), inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        print( re.sub(y, z, line) )
```

Here another idea:

- Instead of processing line-by-line, just read the whole file in as a single string, fix it up, and then write it back.

For example:

```
import re

with open(filename) as f:
    s = f.read()
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    s = re.sub(y, z, s)
    f.write(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your txt save in `src.txt`:

```
morning
night
sun
moon
```

In windows,you can use this batch script,save in `replace.bat`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set filename=%1
set oldstr=%2
set newstr=%3

for /f "usebackq" %%i in (%filename%) do (
    set str=%%i
    set replace=!str:%oldstr%=%newstr%!
    echo !replace!
)
```

Useage:

```
replace.bat src.txt morning afternoon > newsrc.txt
```

or `grepWin`.

Use `sed` or `gawk` may be more simple.

```
sed -i "s/morning/afternoon/g" src.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you are looking for the Python [replace()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) method?

```
str = file.readlines()
str = str.replace(y, z) #this will replace substring y with z within the parent String str
```